# Enable Python to utilize all cores for fitting scikit-learn models

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm running `python 2.7` with `ipython` on Windows 8 64bit with a system that has 4 cores. When fitting a `scikit-learn` model, the CPU usage is 50%, 25% from `python` and 25% from `Chrome`.

Why is `chrome` using as much CPU resources as `python`?

Are there multithreaded version of `scikit-learn` model fitting functions so utilizing multicores can be as easy as setting a variable? Like...

`grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=-1)`

Answer (score 10):

Very few sklearn models can run in parallel by them-selves. `GridSearchCV` with `n_jobs=-1` or `n_jobs=4` in a non `__main__` interactive python session (e.g. in a script) [1] should be able to do multiprocessing under windows (as long as the underlying individual `fit` calls last more than 1s for instance).

The chrome stuff is probably unrelated: just close chrome if you don't want it to use any CPU. You probably have a tab executing some javascript or buggy flash application in the background.

[1] http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows

Comment: Actually `n_jobs` start individual `python` instances on every `fit` call. It results in an enormous overhead, so it's usable with `fit` taking well above 1 second of time.

Comment: It should start `n_jobs` Python process in a Pool and dispatch fit calls to those processes. Indeed this is still significantly more overhead and only useful if individual fit calls takes more than 1s.

Comment: What I see in task manager on Windows is certainly not a pool of `python` processes.